# How do I know when to use a Class, an ID or HTML5 to make layouts in HTML using CSS?

Tags: css, html, layout

I'm building a website and I want to include every element in a separate layout to make it more organized. Just wanna know when it is appropriate to select one or the other. To consider what layout element is best (or preferred) depending the situation. Sometimes I can just use a  tag and insert an ID, or use a Class or use HTML5. Actually, of all the choices HTML5 layouts seem the simpler and easier way to go. I also am considering using tables. Kindly recommend which one to use. Thank you.

Comment: You learn about HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of it as a school

**class** for multiple students (multiple elements)

**id** for a single student (single element)

Comment: Good metaphor. That makes sense.

Comment: But I have been able to use an id tag more than once. Don't quite understand how it is a single element.

Comment: The issue lies more in Javascript where you can use `document.getElementById('your-id')` and it returns a single element whereas `document.getElementsByClassName('your-class')` returns an array-like object. check out this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/y27hL6Lx/1/.

Answer (score 0):

Classes are used when you want to use that CSS for more than one HTML element. They can be used more than once.

IDs are used when you only want to use the CSS one time.

Regarding CSS, there is nothing you can do with an ID that you can't do with a Class and vise versa.

So, when deciding which to use, decide if you want to use that style with more than one element. For example, when making forms that are used multiple times in a website, use a class.

Comment: Don' quite understand, because I can use the id more than once. So for the CSS #someblock I was able to use it twice for different text:<div id="someblock">hello</div><div id="someblock">Hello Hello</div>

Comment: @DanceswithMacs id's are more helpful if you want to link a div